# Functions not triggering in order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, soap

new to WPF and c# hobbyist...

For some reason, I can't get my loadingAnimation (or any other) function to run immediately after a button press and before a SOAP call.

My xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,79,0,0" Name="txtResults" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,29,0,0" Name="txtServiceTag" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <CheckBox Content="This computer's service tag" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,32,0,0" Name="chkThisST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="chkThisST_Checked" Unchecked="chkThisST_Unchecked"/>
    <Button Content="Get Info" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,324,0,0" Name="btnGetInfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnGetInfo_Click" />
    <my:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="128,154,419,127" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="loadingAnimation" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
```

My .cs:

```
    private void btnGetInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtResults.Text = "Retrieving information..."; 
        ShowHideLoading();
        SoapCall();
        ShowHideLoading();
    }
```

My SoapCall() seems to be running before txtResults.Text has time to populate. SoapCall() takes about 5 seconds to return a message. I've messed around with the order of objects in , but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Put a `Tread.Sleep(x);` between the two actions. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it should work.

Comment: Thanks @JanesAbouChleih, but this only delays my soap call. It does not allow time for the textBox or animation to load.

Comment: Which version of the .Net framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `SoapCall()` is blocking the UI thread. In other words, until it is finished - no UI operations will be called.

You can solve this by putting the `SoapCall()` inside a **[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)**.
Then, the  `ShowHideLoading` can be put inside the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event.

Here is an example on [how to use the BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you perform actions on the main thread (in this case, the thread that calls the _Click method.), the UI will not actually update until the call finishes, and the framework alerts the UI to redraw itself.  The reason you're never seeing the update is because the SoapCall is blocking the main thread from performing any updates.

For this to work properly, I would recommend updating the UI, forking a new thread to perform the Soap call, then when the operation completes, reset the UI back to its original state.

You may also want to look at how to use the Dispatcher object correctly, because WPF requires that all UI updates be made on the main thread.  The Dispatcher allows you to force a snippet of code to run on a particular thread.